# How do I get the latitude and longitude information contained csv file?

Tags: geospatial

I have already done a project on "Segmenting and Clustering Neighborhoods in Toronto" using the latitude and longitude information contained CSV file link attached with the question[http://cocl.us/Geospatial_data]. How do I obtain the latitude and longitude information of a given territory?

Comment: What is a 'given territory'?

Comment: Kasaragod district, Kerala state, India

Comment: pincodes of villages are available https://www.mapsofindia.com/pincode/india/kerala/kasargod/. But Latitude longitude information is not available.

Comment: Ok, I think my answer should be useful then. You have enough information to make a query combining the fields.

Answer (score 1):

If what you have are places names and you want to get its coordinates, you can use some library, for example, [geopandas.](http://geopandas.org/) It has the [geocoding](http://geopandas.org/geocoding.html) feature, which converts place names to locations on Earth.

You can also use the [Google maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start).

There are many more API services which solve this problem, but those two should get you started.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. Soon try this. I have another problem.